# Do you have to wear the Hellfire Amulet to get the passive?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to know if it will stack with my others or not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Currently Diablo 3 does not have any inventory charms like Diablo 2 had.  You must equip all items to gain the passive effects.

Comment: As a side note to the stacking bit. The benefits do not stack, if you equip an amulet that gives passive X. Equipping passive as one of your 4 passives will have no effect (if it will even let you equip it at all).